# Crazy div structure CSS - help please

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to do this layout (see image: http://www.pricedesignstudio.com/download/divs.png) and having an issue...I would like the bottom, 100% width (footerBottom) footer to also expand upward to to fill the vertical space between the bottom content block (containerA) and the bottom of the page. I have something similar to this working using absolute positioning and z-index of an additional footer, but I don't think it's optimal. Anyway, easier to show the code than explain I think. Please let me know if you have any input. Thanks in advance!

```
    html, body {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #fff url(images/bkgrnd_main.png) repeat-y center top;
}
.container {
    width: 970px;
    min-height: 95%;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    position:relative;
}
.containerA {
    display:block;
    min-height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
    padding: 0 12px 0 0;
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:100;
}
.containerB {
    display:block;
    min-height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 -10px 0 0;
    padding: 0 12px 0 0;
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:100;
}
.container .inner {
    display:block;
    width:94%;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:150%;
    color: #666;
    padding:12px 0 20px 0;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-top:solid 1px #ccc;
}
#header {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 0 12px 12px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    position:relative;
    text-align: left;
}
#headerTop {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    min-height:80px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:1;
    z-index:0;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 8px 0 0 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:1;
}
#footerBottom {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #999;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    min-height:60px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:1;
    z-index:0;
    text-align:center;
}

    <div id="headerTop"></div>
<div class="container">
<div id="header"></div>
<div class="containerA"></div>
<div class="containerB"></div>
<div class="containerA"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a Photoshop or Illustrator file which has more actual design on it? If you do, export it as a `.png` and show it to us. Although your image and description is helpful, it's still hard to understand what you want. Without looking too hard, I think the CSS could be trimmed down substantially. My best guess so far is changing `min-height:95%` on `.container` to `100%` - that does makes the footer touch the bottom of the page (in Firefox at least). I gave up on IE for the moment when I saw how bad it looked in IE7 (look at it in IE8's Compatibility Mode to see what I mean).

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding! I can't upload images because need a 10 rep, so here's links to mockups:
http://www.pricedesignstudio.com/download/screen1.png

http://www.pricedesignstudio.com/download/screen2.png

I'm on my mac so haven't tested the CSS in IE yet...but I can imagine it's funky.

Comment: I take it that the "white background doesn't quite line up" effect is intentional and desired?

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of the point. Not my design...I'm working on implementing it.

Comment: I have to say, especially on `screen1.png`, it unfortunately just looks *wrong* - like it's an accident. Looking at `screen2.png`, how many "exhibitions" can there be? At the moment there are two ("Joan Jonas"/"New American Voices") - is there always going to be only two, or do you want support for any number?

Comment: 100% on container with a white background and undoing the footer 100% height kind of does the trick. Not exact, but is probably ok.

Answer (score 1):

100% on container with a white background and undoing the footer 100% height kind of does the trick. Not exact, but is probably ok.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the footerBottom doesn't actually lie on the bottom of the space. Is this what you're trying to fix?

I'm confused about the "Footer" div. It points to the same space that "containerA" does in your design, and takes up the entire "container" div's space (because of width and height 100%). Is this intended?

Comment: Yeah, that was a workaround I was playing with in the footer (100% height, z-index putting it behind rest of layout) that I don't really like. It's hacky. I added mockups to the above comment if you want to check them out...maybe better than my original explanation.

Comment: So you need a footer in the middle column container thingy, and then a big 100% width footer below that (the whitespace in your mockups)?